# Error when build Apk

Tags: android

my build.gradle

```
//dependencies {
compile project(':appRater')
compile project(':circularImageView')
compile project(':facebookSDK')
compile project(':paperSlidingTab')
compile project(':library')
compile project(':urlImageViewHelper')
compile project(':pullToRefreshLi')
compile project(':libraries:SlidingMenu:library')
compile files('libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.2.5.jar')
compile files('libs/json-org.jar')
compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.1-with-sources.jar')
compile files('libs/WebSocket.jar')
compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
compile files('libs/applause-sdk-library-2.0.0.jar')
compile 'org.droidparts:droidparts:1.+'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.+'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android2:1.+'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.+'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android2:1.+'
compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.+'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.+'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:11.+'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.+'
compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.+'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 17
}

signingConfigs {
    release {
        if (System.getenv("GRADLE_KEYSTORE")) {
            storeFile = file(System.getenv("GRADLE_KEYSTORE"))
            storePassword = System.getenv("GRADLE_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")
            keyAlias = System.getenv("GRADLE_KEY_ALIAS")
            keyPassword = System.getenv("GRADLE_KEY_PASSWORD")
        }
    }
}

buildTypes.debug {
    ext.enableCrashlytics = false
}

buildTypes.release {
    debuggable false
    zipAlignEnabled true
    minifyEnabled false
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}

lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
    // but continue the build even when errors are found:
    abortOnError false
}
}
```

my error message is:

> WarningDependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is
>   ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version
>   provided by Android.

please help me to fix this

Comment: thx guys..i waiting for answer nih :D

Comment: what dependencies in main project?

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude dependencies in the **build.gradle** file of your module.

```
compile ('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android2:1.+'){
 exclude(group: 'com.google.android.gms:play-services', module: 'google-play-services')
}
```

Comment: its mean all build.gradle from library or main app?

Comment: i get this   error Error:Execution failed for task ':library:prepareReleaseDependencies'.
> ERROR: Release has an indirect dependency on Android API level 7, but minSdkVersion for variant 'release' is API level 4